# In AS3 how to load image from rss feed file into text box in AIR for Android

Tags: android, air, xml-parsing, actionscript-3

I can load images from feed file into text box in normal flash as3 application,
but When I load same file into Air for Android it does't work.
here is the code please read and help me.

"This is Air application for Android in flash as3"

```
var txt:TextField = new TextField();

addChild(txt);

txt.htmlText="image url"
```

from the above code image is not loading.

but the same code works in normal flash as3.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use StageWebView for displaying html content (like an image in your example)?

also if the html text didn't worked have you considered using Loader class

```
var img:Loader = new Loader();
    img.load(new URLRequest("image url"));
    addChild(img);
```

also the sample above doesn't include vital parts like IOError handling and other elements but this you can find on your own:)

best regards